# How to move decimal place 2 positions to the right in SQL, not converting or rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal

I am trying convert a version number to the correct format as it is appending with other data in the database.  I am using `substring` to pull the last 6 digits of the messed up version number and what I get is the last 6 digits but the decimal place is 2 digits further up than it should be do to the way it is formatted in the database.  What I am trying to do is just move that decimal place two digits over if possible.  This is the driver version I have

```
25.21.14.2600
```

What I need is the last 6 with two decimal points to the right

```
426.00
```

I have looked for answers on this and have tried what I have seen which is

```
CONVERT(DECIMAL,SUBSTRING(vc.DriverVersion0,8,6))/100
```

but this rounds it and moves the decimal place. I have tried using `Replace`

```
Replace(SUBSTRING(vc.DriverVersion0,8,6),'.','')
```

Which that works to remove it but I don't know how I can add a decimal to it after that, would be nice if I could just move but either one works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: `SUBSTRING` won't "move" the position of a decimal point, and neither will `CONVERT`. Providing a [mre] here is really going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . I'm not sure which way you want to move it.  But you can use `stuff()` and `charindex()`:

```
select stuff(replace(str, '.', ''), charindex('.', str) + 2, 0, '.')
```

I'm not sure if you want `+ 2` or `- 2`, though.

So this code:

```
select stuff(replace(str, '.', ''), charindex('.', str) + 2, 0, '.')
from (values ('a.bcdef'), ('123.456')) v(str)
```

Returns:

```
abc.def
12345.6
```

This code:

```
select stuff(replace(str, '.', ''), charindex('.', str) - 2, 0, '.')
from (values ('abcde.f'), ('123.456')) v(str)
```

Returns:

```
abc.def
1.23456
```

Comment: +2 is the ticket.  thanks.  What is that function, stuff?  how can find where these exist?

Comment: @Keets um, the official SQL Server documentation lists all functions which are available for use.

Comment: @DaleK um thanks, ill look into that, thought there was something I could view inside SSMS that would list functions